# Youtube api request cost

Tags: youtube-api, limit, quota

I have already tried calculating cost for search with list and snippet at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost and it shows 100.

Is there any additional cost for more parameters like chart and region code with search method.

To be specific, what will be the cost for the following query:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=...&chart=mostRecent&regionCode=IN&key=...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional cost for queries.
The cost will be 100 for search with part=snippet.